# Telephone Directory

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a telephone directory, which asks user for name to be searched and then displays information corresponding to that name. But when i am using infoList[i] to compare with searchName instead of Rohan, it does not go into the if statement. i have also tried using foreach loop, still no result.... Please keep in mind while answering that i am a beginner :P

```
 class Directory
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string email_id { get; set; }
        public double phone_number { get; set; }

        public Directory(string n, string a, string e, double p)
        {
            this.name = n;
            this.address = a;
            this.email_id = e;
            this.phone_number = p;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string searchName;
            List<Directory> infoList = new List <Directory>();
            infoList.Add(new Directory("Rohan ", "Pashan ", "rohan.nevrikar@gmail.com ", 9974177791));
            infoList.Add(new Directory("Prithvi  ", "Naroda ", "prithvi.nirban@gmail.com ", 9974177792));
            infoList.Add(new Directory("Aagam  ", "Akshardham ", "aagam.nevrikar@gmail.com ", 9974177793));
            Console.Write("Which person's info do you want to search?? \n");
            searchName = Console.ReadLine();
            for(int i=0;i<infoList.Count;i++)
            {
                if (string.Compare(searchName, "Rohan") == 0)   
                {
                    Console.Write("Name : " + infoList[i].name + "\n");
                    Console.Write("Address : " + infoList[i].address + "\n");

                    Console.Write("Email id : " + infoList[i].email_id + "\n");

                    Console.Write("Phone number : " + infoList[i].phone_number + "\n");
                    break;
                }
            }                 
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code will only display the information if you enter "Rohan" from the keyboard because your string compare if comparing what was entered to the literal sting "Rohan".  If you want to display information any name change the if line to:

```
if (string.Compare (searchName, infoList[i].name) == 0)
```

Also note that when you create the entries in the `infoList` each name has two spaces at the end, so you need to enter these spaces in order for the `string.Compare` to find the exact match.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot friend.... i had used using infoList[i] instead of Rohan at the first place, but i didnt consider the spaces as you said... yeah that was so silly haha.... thanks a lot man!

Comment: @RohanNevrikar Instead of leaving a comment consider [accepting an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)